# "Dynamic Option Creation" (select2) & collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have select2 gem successfully running on my rails site and have also successfully utilised the "Dynamic Option Creation" on a basic "select" method

I want to try to add the "Dynamic Option Creation" to a collection_select, but I am hitting a brick wall.  I have a feeling I need to use the ".find_or_create_by" in my controller.

Any help is appreciated - below is my existing code.  Every "BusinessOwner" has a Group, and I want users to be able to add a new Group (when not on teh list) when creating a new "BusinessOwner"

In the code, I have tried to replace BusinessOwner.new with BusinessOwner.find_or_create_by and if utilising an existing "group" it works fine, but if I try to add a new "group" it returns the error > "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"

CONTROLLER >

```
  def create

    @Owner = BusinessOwner.new(owner_params)

    if @Owner.save
      redirect_to business_index_path, notice: 'success'
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'issue'
      render :new
    end

  end

  def owner_params
    params.require(:business_owner).permit!
  end
```

VIEW >

```
<%= f.collection_select :group_id, Group.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a Group"}, {class: "form-control dynamic-form"} %>
```

BusinessOwner MODEL >

```
class BusinessOwner < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :businesses
    has_many :business_owners
    has_many :owners, :through => :business_owners
    belongs_to :group, optional: true
end
```

Erro in full when trying to add new "Group" (after changing to BusinessOwner.find_or_create_by(owner_params) >

> SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: INSERT
>   INTO "business_owners" ("group_id", "name", "created_at",
>   "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Hi - can you please edit your question and add your `borrower_params` method and also a look into your relevant models? Plus tell us more about the foreign-key constraint? which one failed and what is it constraining? cheers :)

Comment: Added more details as requested :->

Comment: Great! So... I'm assuming there's more to your view than you've got up there - because how do you enter a new group (one that doesn't exist) in order to create it? Can you give us an example of the find_or_create code that you are trying (that isn't working?) Can you tell us which foreign-key constraint is failing and what it's meant to be protecting? My best guess would be that you're trying to create a group and including the group_id... instead of just creating a group using its attributes, but all the info will help confirm/deny that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - Figured it out (after much trial & error!)

Basically, I utilised find_or_initialize_by and it works a dream (after reworking the controller & view quite a bit)